# What does C++ standard say about dynamic libraries?

Tags: c++, dynamic-linking, dynamic-library

What does C++ standard say about dynamic libraries? I heard that it completely ignores them (for some reason) - if it's true, why so?

Comment: What would a dynamic library look like on the "Abstract Machine" that the C++ Standard addresses?

Comment: Removed `language-lawyer`, since you're looking for an explanation, not a standard quote.

Comment: I am not al all a C++ standard expert, but I would guess the Standard similarly ignores concepts like static libraries, object files, executable files, maybe even source files, since it aims to be abstract enough.

Comment: In principle it says (almost) nothing about dll's. It is mostly a link time dependency not a compile time one

Comment: It's not _entirely_ ignored. To support `dlopen`/`GetProcAddress`, C++11 added _conditionally-supported_ casts. It was UB in C++98.

Comment: @PepijnKramer The Standard has the concept of multiple translation units forming a single, executable program, but it doesn't really specify that there need to be (compiled) object files as components, or anything about how any 'linker' would work. The final program *could* be formed during the multi-TU compilation phase.

Comment: C++ Draft Standard [\[intro.abstract\]](https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.abstract)  _"...Rather, conforming implementations are required to emulate (only) the observable behavior of the abstract machine as explained below..."_

Comment: C++ needs not be "compiled". You could implement a JIT C++ compiler and still be C++ compliant. You could even develop a C++ interpreter and the C++ Standard should be relevant still.

Comment: The C++ standard specifies an abstract machine, and how C++ code (including language constructs and library features) is diagnosed or translated to produce observable behaviour of that abstract machine.    The standard doesn't specify how an implementation (e.g. a compiler and associated implementation of the standard library) performs that translation between code and observable behaviour of an actual target machine.   Dynamic libraries are not part of the abstract machine, nor required to be supported by an implementation (compiler, host platform, etc).

Comment: DLLs are typically implemented by the OS replacing 'placeholder' function stubs at runtime. That sort of implementation detail would be akin to how an OS *actually* implements low-level I/O to/from a storage device, for example. The Standard doesn't 'care' how that's done, so long as it produces results that comply with it's stipulations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are, effectively, just 2 major pitfalls with dynamic libraries, where you *can* trivially break the assumptions made in the C++ Standard such that it doesn't match the [abstract machine](https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.abstract):

- Violating the "One Definition" rule: e.g., you have managed to dynamically link two libraries with different implementations of the same symbol; each one has, for some reason, preferred *local* linkage and, depending on who calls, a different implementation is used. The C++ spec still tells you what you are allowed to do, even though the compiler, linker and dynamic loader can be easily configured to violate that rule.

  In this case, the default you have, e.g., on Linux systems with `ld-linux + gcc + ld`, with public visibility for *all* symbols, means that *all* symbols are resolved by the dynamic loader at runtime, which actually fits the description of the abstract machine.

  Unfortunately this default is not preferable at all, for performance reasons. Limiting visibility of symbols is the prerequisite to allow even the most basic forms of inlining optimizations.
- Loading and unloading libraries at unexpected times: This means pointers (to code and data segments) can become (or remain) invalid at arbitrary times, which doesn't match the abstract state machine at all.

In both cases, it's still your responsibility as a developer to ensure that you stay within the bounds of the abstract machine, and not cause any observable behavior which would contradict it.

So much for the theory.

The reality is that, in both cases, most dynamic libraries actually don't even *try* to act as if the system/process as a whole was compliant with the C++ abstract machine.

Instead, C++ is only expected to be fully functional *within* each dynamic library, while the entire external interface is entirely aware of dynamic linkage, symbol visibility etc., and avoids any C++ features which could potentially expose undefined behavior on the boundaries. Each library – *on its own* – acts in compliance with the abstract machine.